# How can I add new radio buttons without unchecking old ones?

Tags: javascript, html

I have to create new group of radio buttons with each group having diff names. I am done with that part. But the thing is when I select one option on the first radio group and click add button to add new radio group the old one refreshes and the checks are gone. Any possible ways to overcome it?
Here is my logic

```html
    <div id="sub-container">
            <div class="input-container">                       
                    <input type="radio" name="radio-grp" value="10" > <label>O</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio-grp" value="9" > <label>A+</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio-grp" value="8" > <label>A</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio-grp" value="7" > <label>B+</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio-grp" value="6" > <label>B</label>
                        
                    <select id="credits-option">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>1.5</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                    </select>
                <input class="credit-acquired" type="text" placeholder="credits acquired" readonly value="">
            </div>
    </div>
```

```js
var index = 1;
function addSubject() {
    var element = `<div class="input-container">                        
                <input type="radio" name="radio-grp${index}" value="10" onclick="onButtonClick(this)"> <label>O</label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-grp${index}" value="9" onclick="onButtonClick(this)"> <label>A+</label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-grp${index}" value="8" onclick="onButtonClick(this)"> <label>A</label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-grp${index}" value="7" onclick="onButtonClick(this)"> <label>B+</label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-grp${index}" value="6" onclick="onButtonClick(this)"> <label>B</label>
                
                <select id="credits-option" onchange="onSelectChange(this)">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>1.5</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                </select>
                <input class="credit-acquired" type="text" placeholder="credits acquired" readonly value="">
            </div>`;
    var x = document.getElementById("sub-container");
    index++;
    x.innerHTML += element; 
}
```